# Is it possible to edit an Acumatica company snapshot XML?

Tags: acumatica

It seems that one of the advantages to being able to export a snapshot in XML format is the ability to compare and merge changes between environments.

However, when I try to do this, zip the XML files again, and Import them, I get an error "Invalid snapshot format"

Is there a method to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I have done it before, but my results have been hit or miss depending on which values you are updating. Any specifics as to what you need to change related to a snapshot such as field size? excluding tables, included/exclude specific data?, etc.?

Comment: It should work just fine, are you sure the files were valid XML after modification and that the ZIP file was created with same structure?

Comment: I'm mostly adding data.  I'll review to ensure that the XML structure didn't get hosed, and maybe try subbing the files into the original ZIP file instead of zipping it myself.  Are there any particular zip programs that have proven successful?

Comment: make sure when you zip it up you do not add a additional layer to the zip. For example after you zip you should be able to open the zip file and see all files listed (not a single folder). Could be you are zipping it up incorrectly? And i have not tried to add data to the snapshots. I know you can make your own snapshot config file that you can use to create snapshots from but that usually involves leaving out data (not adding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the advice!  The problem was indeed that I was zipping the extracted folder rather than just the contents.  Doh!